# Swift does not import typedef from Objective-C Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, typedef, mmdrawercontroller

It seems that Swift does not recognize a typedef in a Objective-C-Header as I get following error:

**Could not find a user-defined conversion from type 'MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock!' to type '(MMDrawerController!, MMDrawerSide, CGFloat) -> Void'**

I use the [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) which is written in Objective-C, my own code though is in Swift.

The typedef looks like this:

```
typedef void (^MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock)(MMDrawerController * drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible);
```

Here are more code snippets for clarity:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func initDrawerController() {
    drawerController = MMDrawerController(centerViewController: centerController, leftDrawerViewController: leftDrawerController, rightDrawerViewController: rightDrawerController)
    drawerController?.setDrawerVisualStateBlock(MMDrawerVisualState.parallaxVisualStateBlockWithParallaxFactor(2.0))
}
```

**MMDrawerController.h**

```
typedef void (^MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock)(MMDrawerController * drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible);

@interface MMDrawerController : UIViewController
-(void)setDrawerVisualStateBlock:(void(^)(MMDrawerController * drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible))drawerVisualStateBlock;
@end
```

**MMDrawerVisualState.h**

```
@interface MMDrawerVisualState : NSObject
+(MMDrawerControllerDrawerVisualStateBlock)parallaxVisualStateBlockWithParallaxFactor:(CGFloat)parallaxFactor;
@end
```

**Module-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "MMDrawerController.h"
#import "MMDrawerVisualState.h"
```

When building this, I get an error in my AppDelegate for the Expression with `setDrawerVisualStateBlock`, although there is a typedef in the `MMDrawerController.h`:

Is this a bug (because on Objective-C, it works fine)? Or is there anyone who knows/has an idea how to deal with it?
Help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C typedef declaration (in MMDrawerController.h for example) :

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MMDrawerOpenCenterInteractionMode) {
    MMDrawerOpenCenterInteractionModeNone,
    MMDrawerOpenCenterInteractionModeFull,
    MMDrawerOpenCenterInteractionModeNavigationBarOnly,
};
```

In Swift, it’s imported like this :

```
enum MMDrawerOpenCenterInteractionMode: NSInteger {
    case None
    case Full
    case Only
}
```

So you can use this syntax in Swift :

```
var mmDrawerViewController:MMDrawerController! = ....... ;
mmDrawerViewController.centerHiddenInteractionMode = MMDrawerOpenCenterInteractionMode.Full;
```

For use mmDrawerViewController.setDrawerVisualStateBlock()
try

```
mmDrawerViewController.setDrawerVisualStateBlock{ (drawerController:MMDrawerController!, drawerSlide:MMDrawerSide!, cgFloat:CGFloat!) -> Void in
    println("setDrawerVisualStateBlock");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah but you cant use the default blocks like `MMDrawerVisualState.swingingDoorVisualStateBlock()`

Comment: Change NSUInteger to NSInteger helps me.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you access `MMDrawerSide drawerSide` but are probably not importing the file that declares `MMDrawerSide` in your bridging header.

If an Objective-C method declaration accesses a class which is not imported in your bridging header, Swift doesn't import nor recognize that method.

So, if you have a typedef in Objective-C like this:

`typedef void (^someBlock)(MMSomeClass *someInstance);`

Then you must make sure that `MMSomeClass` is imported in your bridging header.